# how to set a column to fetch the date now?

Tags: firebird

hi i have a sample table named datenow and used the following to create my table on flamerobin to have a column that gets the date today automatically when an entry is added.

```
CREATE TABLE "DATENOW"
(
  ID Char(8) NOT NULL,
  "Start_Date" Char(10),
  "Client_Name" Varchar(30),
  BALANCE Integer,
  select cast('Now' as date) from rdb$database
  CONSTRAINT PK_datenow PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON "datenow" TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

also tried inserting these sql statement

```
select date 'Now' from rdb$database
select time 'now' from rdb$database
select timestamp 'NOW' from rdb$database
```

but i cannot generate a table and cant determine where will i put the sql statement or what to do in order to have a column that gets the date today automat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE "DATENOW"
(
  ID Char(8) NOT NULL,
  "Start_Date" Char(10),
  "Client_Name" Varchar(30),
  BALANCE Integer,
  Now_Column TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT PK_datenow PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

If you `INSERT` into the table, and ommit a value for `Now_Column` (IE: it's `NULL`), the current timestamp will be used instead.

Also, never use `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` datatypes to hold dates (which I suspect you are trying to do with your `Start_Date` column) - use proper date datatypes.

*Untested, by the way - this is from the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-current_timestamp.html)*.

Comment: thanks will try this now sorry for the late reply i was also testing some statements :D edit: the above statement worked. thank you. btw what would be the effect if i dont use proper datatypes for my fields?

Comment: @ChunkChunk What would happen? You'll end up with rows that have `'2013-04-31'` as a date or `'2013-04-32'` or `'2013-13-62'` or even `'NewYearEve'`

Comment: @ypercube oic thanks for the info. btw how can i get a timestamp to display the date only without the time?

Comment: @chunkchunk For that you use `DATE` instead